# Class Diagram in PowerDesigner 15 and C# 3.0 Properties

Tags: powerdesigner

I am using PowerDesigner 15 and I want the generated code preview of each class designed to be using C# 3.0 Properties, not attributes and a "set_Att get_Att" of java!

How can I do it?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

PowerDesigner 15.3 only supports C# 2.0.

You will have to edit the language definition yourself...

`C# 2::Profile\Attribute\Stereotypes\Property\Templates\definition` seems to be a good starting place, with the related `C# 2::Profile\Attribute\Stereotypes\Property\Templates\Helpers\getOperation`...